# Don't know how to execute function after else command

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gmail, fingerprint

I'm trying to take an image via webcam then send the image through gmail. That function suppose to happen if my fingerprint is known at the system. If it does it needs to execute the send email function. I added after the send email function to send 'HIGH' to a gpio. I don't think it suppose to interfere.

When there is a known template it is followed by an "else:" statement. then I put my "def find_newest_file(dir):" function. What am I doing wrong?
might note I'm terrible at programming. Thank you!

Pyfingerprint

```
import os
import glob
import time
import smtplib
import imghdr
from email.message import EmailMessage
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT)
import hashlib
from pyfingerprint.pyfingerprint import PyFingerprint

GPIO.output(26, 0)
## Search for a finger
##

## Tries to initialize the sensor
try:
    f = PyFingerprint('/dev/ttyUSB0', 57600, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00000000)

    if ( f.verifyPassword() == False ):
        raise ValueError('The given fingerprint sensor password is wrong!')

except Exception as e:
    print('The fingerprint sensor could not be initialized!')
    print('Exception message: ' + str(e))
    exit(1)

## Gets some sensor information
print('Currently used templates: ' + str(f.getTemplateCount()) +'/'+ str(f.getStorageCapacity()))

## Tries to search the finger and calculate hash
try:
    print('Waiting for finger...')

    ## Wait that finger is read
    while ( f.readImage() == False ):
        pass

    ## Converts read image to characteristics and stores it in charbuffer 1
    f.convertImage(0x01)

    ## Searchs template
    result = f.searchTemplate()

    positionNumber = result[0]
    accuracyScore = result[1]

    if ( positionNumber == -1 ):
        print('No match found!')
        exit(0)
    else:
        print('Found template at position #' + str(positionNumber))
        print('The accuracy score is: ' + str(accuracyScore))

             def find_newest_file(dir):
                 os.system('fswebcam -r 1280x720 -S 3 --jpeg 90 --save /home/pi/Pictures/%H%M%S.jpg')
                 types = ['*.png', '*.jpg'] 
                 files = []
                 if not os.path.isdir(dir):
                     print(f'ERROR: {dir} does not exist. or it is not a valid folder')
                     exit()
            for ext in types:
                scan_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir, ext))
                files.extend(glob.glob(scan_path))
       
            if len(files) == 0:
                print(f'ERROR: file not found  while scanning folder: {dir} for: {types}')
                exit()
        
            newest = None
            n_time = 0
            for file in files:
        # print(file)
            c_time = os.path.getctime(file)
            if c_time > n_time:
                n_time = c_time
                newest = file
    
           if newest is None:
               print(f'-----------\nUnexpected error: None was return while the list was not empty:\n{files}')
               exit()
        
           if os.path.exists(newest):
               return newest  # return as a list since this is what Yehonata expect
           else:
               print(f'ERROR: File {newest} not found')
               exit()

# Yehontan Code
        Sender_Email = "Sender@gmail.com"
        Reciever_Email = "reciver@gmailcom"
        Password = input('Enter your email account password: ')

        newMessage = EmailMessage()
        newMessage['Subject'] = "Check out the new logo" 
        newMessage['From'] = Sender_Email
        newMessage['To'] = Reciever_Email
        newMessage.set_content('Let me know what you think. Image attached!')

# Tomerl: Replace static name with seach function
        files = [ find_newest_file('/home/pi/Pictures/') ]

        for file in files:
            with open(file, 'rb') as f:

            image_data = f.read()
            image_type = imghdr.what(f.name)
            image_name = f.name

                newMessage.add_attachment(image_data, maintype='image', subtype=image_type, filename=image_name)

            with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:

        smtp.login(Sender_Email, Password)
        smtp.send_message(newMessage)
try:
    for x in range(1):
        GPIO.output(26, 1)
        sleep(2.5)
        GPIO.output(26, 0)
        sleep(2.5)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
    GPIO.output(26, 0)

    ## Loads the found template to charbuffer 1
    f.loadTemplate(positionNumber, 0x01)

    ## Downloads the characteristics of template loaded in charbuffer 1
    characterics = str(f.downloadCharacteristics(0x01)).encode('utf-8')

    ## Hashes characteristics of template
    print('SHA-2 hash of template: ' + hashlib.sha256(characterics).hexdigest())

except Exception as e:
    print('Operation failed!')
    print('Exception message: ' + str(e))
    exit(1)
```

Comment: it might be code formatting here, but you have a bunch on indentation problems. You might consider moving the function def outside your try, maybe right under your imports.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the function at the top of the program. You only need to call it after the else statement. Basically, put

```
def find_newest_file(dir):
             os.system('fswebcam -r 1280x720 -S 3 --jpeg 90 --save /home/pi/Pictures/%H%M%S.jpg')
             types = ['*.png', '*.jpg'] 
             files = []
             if not os.path.isdir(dir):
                 print(f'ERROR: {dir} does not exist. or it is not a valid folder')
                 exit()
```

at the top and when you want to use it do

```
find_newest_file(foo)
```

Good luck on your journey!